# Why didn't Pegasus just take Yugi's puzzle when he first "won" against him?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Not sure if it was different in the manga, but in the anime, Yugi (Well okay, Atem) dueled Pegasus through a magic TV, lost, and so he took Grandpa's soul and told Yugi the only way he was getting it back was to enter the Duelist Kingdom Tournament and try and make it the finals to duel Pegasus one last time, but if he lost that duel, Pegasus would get his Millenium Puzzle. The whole reason he challenged Yugi in the first place.

So why didn't he just take it the first time?

Instead of just taking his Grandpa's soul, why didn't Pegasus just take Yugi's Millennium Puzzle? Penalty games seem to not have any limits to what a person can "wager," and I heard in the manga the things a person could lose range from sanity to even their luck, so why wouldn't Pegasus use his ancient Egyptian magic to take Yugi's puzzle after he beat him? Was his motivation different in the manga? In the Japanese version of the anime?

Answer (score -2):

## Answer 1 - Magic cannot teleport objects.

The puzzle is a physical object. A soul isn't.

Magic cannot teleport objects. Otherwise why later in battle city did Marik play Yugi with a physical Slifer deck instead of just playing remotely and then teleporting the cards eg give Slifer remotely if Marik lost?

From reddit user The_Doolinator [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/ws368z/comment/ikw6on5/?context=3):

> Honestly teleportation seems to be a very rare, almost nonexistent magical power (I think Shadi is the only who utilizes it, and I’d chalk that up more to him being a spirit. You could make an argument for Bakura too (the ring rematerializes on him after he was separated from it) but he is at least part dark god so there’s that).
>
> So yeah, teleportation is probably just not a power normally at the disposal of other item holders and those able to use it are tapping into something specific to them.
>
> Or the real reason: powers as the plot demands.

---

## Answer 2 - It was a dub thing.

From reddit users

tokarooni [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/ws368z/comment/ikwobgc/?context=3):

> Pegasus wanting the puzzle was a dub only thing. In the original he just needed to beat Yugi publicly as part of the conditions for taking over Kaibacorp.

Verificus [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/ws368z/comment/ikwqt8k/?context=3):

> Pegasus didn’t want a puzzle or soul in original manga and original anime. Just something 4kids added.

MaCl97 [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/ws368z/comment/ikwqwjr/?context=3):

> he never wanted it in the manga. He just wants to beat the guy who beat Kaiba and take over kaiba corp. Marik too, he doesn't want the puzzle. He just wants to kill the pharaoh.

## Source for Answer 2:

See for yourself in episodes 35-39, a sub-arc called [Match of the Millenium](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yugi_Muto,_Yami_Yugi_and_Maximillion_Pegasus%27_Duelist_Kingdom_Duel), specifically the middle episode, episode 37 ([fandom doesn't point this out though](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_-_Episode_037#Differences_in_adaptations)). There's a part in the 4kids dub just after Yugi and Atem destroy the toon monsters and just before Pegasus makes the game into a shadow game where Pegasus says like 'if I win, then I plan to claim your puzzle.'

Compare the original anime, the original Japanese manga or even the Singaporean dub. There is no such thing that Pegasus says.

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7CVTmFxP_4) (22:00 - 23:40) for example in the original anime. Pegasus acknowledges Yugi and Atem have a millennium item, but Pegasus doesn't explicitly express any interest in claiming the millennium puzzle.

Comment: reddit users are no better than hearsay and unreliable sources, even if what they claim can be considered accurate. please cite proper sources for your answers, for an example subs for the original series.

Comment: @кяαzєя Have you seen Yu-Gi-Oh! ? Anyone who's seen the original Japanese can check for themselves...

Comment: @кяαzєя Btw, I think it's the same as citing [fandom site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266389/howd-the-fire-nation-justify-its-war-was-there-some-kind-of-propaganda-that-th). It's not just 1 reddit user but several.

Comment: Fandom sites are tertiary sources and just as bad, but unverified hearsay is even worse. Anyone can say anything about something, but why do you just take their word for it. Any one can check for themselves, but the burden of proof of on the one that answers the question. Even a citation from the manga is better that something so redditor said. It you want to enjoy series don't just corners and read summaries. If you want to help someone, don't have someone else do your homework for you.